# Simple Syntax Error Driving me Crazy - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the Blog app from the RoR download site. The tutorial says enter this code to get some validation:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

I've got this in my copy:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
validates :name,  :presence => true,
validates :title,  :presence => true,
         :length =>  {  :minimum => 5  }

end
```

Which, as far as I can see, is correct, however I get these error messages when I run the page:

```
c:/Sites/blog/app/models/post.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
validates :Title,  :presence => true,
           ^
C:/Sites/blog/app/models/post.rb:3: Can't assign to true
C:/Sites/blog/app/models/post.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
         :length =>  {  :minimum => 5  }
```

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong? It seems exactly the same to me.

Answer (score 11):

You have a comma at the end of `validates :name, :presence => true` in your `post.rb` file; delete it.

Answer (score 6):

```
validates :name,  :presence => true,
```

should be:

```
validates :name,  :presence => true
```

(note the comma removed at the end)

Answer (score 3):

Be first indentation but I already ran well and if I worked anyway .. leave the code as I'm working.

Here is the code I use:

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates:name, :presence=>true
      validates:title,:presence=>true,
               :length=>{:minimum=>5}   
  end
```

Comment: No need for the good luck & greetings, a simple answer will do :)

Comment: I think you're missing some formatting and validate should be validates

Comment: Also, :presence is a symbol (like :length) and so the colon is required

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma on the line `validates :name,  :presence => true`.

Comment: Cheers guys, been staring at it for too long!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error a while ago, and I put some attributes into the code so that it was fixed.

Your code must be like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title
  validates name, :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true, length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

It worked for me.